# Java Spring: How to access the originating request from ClientResponse?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web-services, spring-webflux

#### Background

The class [`ClientResponse`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ClientResponse.html) most probably internally has access to **the originating request**, as is clued by the documentation of methods such as [createError()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ClientResponse.html#createError()):

> Create a `Mono` that terminates with a `WebClientResponseException`, containing the response status, headers, body, and **the originating request**.

#### Question

Is there a way to access the originating request from the `ClientResponse`?

#### Motivation behind

I am writing my own [`ExchangeFilterFunction`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ExchangeFilterFunction.html) using [`ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ExchangeFilterFunction.html#ofResponseProcessor(java.util.function.Function)) inside which I want to access *also* the originating request:

```java
@Bean
public ExchangeFilterFunction logResponse() {
    return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(response -> {
        return Mono.just(response)
            .doOnEach(resp -> log.info("""
                        {} {}
                        {}
                        Response Headers: {}""",
                ORIG_METHOD, ORIG_URI, // Here I need the originating request
                response.statusCode(),
                response.headers().asHttpHeaders())
            );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can access ClientRequest from ClientResponse,
but you can have access to both of them using ExchangeFilterFunction

ExchangeFilterFunction is a @FunctionalInterface
that means we can use simple lambda for this task

```
@Bean
public ExchangeFilterFunction logResponse() {
    return (request, next) -> {
    // here you have access to request object
        return next.exchange(request)
                   .doOnEach(response -> {/*here you have access to request AND response objects*/});
    };
}
```

Also you are using [Mono.doOnEach](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#doOnEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) which takes Consumer<Signal<ClientResponse>> as argument
I would recommend to switch to [Mono.doOnNext](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#doOnNext-java.util.function.Consumer-) to have access to ClientResponse rather than Signal<ClientResponse>

So your example (without brackets) would look like this:

```
@Bean
public ExchangeFilterFunction logResponse() {
    return (request, next) -> 
        next.exchange(request)
            .doOnNext(response -> 
                log.info("""
                    {} {}
                    {}
                    Response Headers: {}""",
                request.method(), 
                request.url,
                response.statusCode(),
                response.headers().asHttpHeaders()));
```